# VHDL configuration for packages

Tags: configuration, package, vhdl

I have two packages (pkg1 and pkg2), which one contain a set of constants.

Depending on the configuration, I want to use either pkg1 or pkg2, but not both together.

So, how can I do this in VHDL? How to define the configuration for the packages?

Comment: It is doable in different ways, either by making a pkg3 with the selected constants, or by expressions in an entity, so please show some code with the background for the question.

Comment: "either by making a pkg3 with the selected constants" - how can I do so, could you please elaborate? "or by expressions in an entity" - using generics?

Comment: The solution really depends on what kind of control you have for configuration; is that constants in another package, or generics on a module?  Also, do you want the configuration to allow use of all from a module (if configuration is in another package), or do you need some third set of constants to be defined in an entity?  For this reason it makes it easy to get a useful answer if you elaborated on the specific conditions with an update to the question, preferable with the code you have so far.

Answer (score 0):

vhdl does not have some preprocessor to manipulate code like verilog

you can't define use package statement in different cases.

but you can use constants with different names for each case and
if - generate - statement like so:

```
    package pkg is
      constant case_1;
      constant case_2;
    end pkg;
```

then in your architecture block:

```
    if condition1 generate
      signal1 <= case_1;
    end generate;

    if condition2 generate
      signal1 <= case_2;
    end generate;
```

the compiler/synthesizer would terminate unusable constants.

hope could help you

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same need. I have a large core that does a lot of stuff and depending on the machine I want to build, there are constant value changes (ADC, DACs and other varying hardware). The way I solved it is by having a top folder for the project ( all the common files) and a subfolder per machine. Inside each subfolders, I have the VHDL files (packages, entity, architectures) specific to each machine. The Machine specific files are compiled in a "machine" library instead of "work". Then, I tell the compiler (simulator or synthesis) where the "machine" library source are located (the subfolder).